# putting in a JQuery input during a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running a loop and I want a jQuery function to happen before the loop continues.
here is an example.

```
var battle=true;

while(battle){
 $('.action1').click(n=0);
 $('.action2').click(n=1);
 $('.action3').click(n=2);
 $('.action4').click(n=3);

action[n]
etc....
}
```

I am currently making a text based rpg game. Whenever user input was needed I would use a prompt() and whenever user information was given I would use an alert().

is there some way for me to have the while loop progress through receiving user input and giving input result by the user clicking on html elements?

Comment: No there is not, at least I think not if I'm getting what you're trying to do? By the time you return something to the while loop, your browser is hanging due to the gazillion iterations it's trying to do

Comment: to infinity and beyond!

Comment: So there is no way for me to have a loop stop and wait for user input or anything like that?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make a function call from the loop like this:

```
function battle(){
    var battle=true;

    while(battle){
         $('.action1').click(n=0);
         $('.action2').click(n=1);
         $('.action3').click(n=2);
         $('.action4').click(n=3);

        myFunction();
    }
}


function myFunction(){
    //do somethhing
}
```

if you want to stop the loop just use the keyword:

```
break;
```

If you want pause execution waiting for user input read this stackoverflow question: [JavaScript pausing execution of function to wait for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551378/javascript-pausing-execution-of-function-to-wait-for-user-input)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that my code is kind of long.

Comment: @VioleBaam that means nothing at all! Did you use this? if so please thumbs up so I get credit ... if not tell me why and I'll correct it.

Comment: I have multiple instances where user input is needed and information needs to be shown to the user do I need to make all cases a loop? not to be rude but I don't really see how this solution helps.