# update display in loop when drawing many d3 svg objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I draw many circles with some loops via d3.js

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
var  r = 1


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height",1000)

for ( var x=0; x< 1000 ; x+=3*r)
  {
    for ( var y=0; y< 1000 ; y+=3*r)
    {
      svg.append("circle")
          .attr("cx", x)
          .attr("cy", y)
          .attr("r", r)
    }
  }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4e769vpy/2/)

It seems the browser refreshes the display only after the loops have finished. Then all objects appear at once. How can I force a refresh after every element, so I can watch the progress of the image?

Thanks

Comment: Do an few at a time in a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) callback

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Made a [fiddle to compare both](http://jsfiddle.net/ffdzvLrh/)

Answer (score 0):

I would create the data separately and then use a transition:

```
var data = [];
for ( var x=0; x< 1000 ; x+=3*r) {
  for ( var y=0; y< 1000 ; y+=3*r) {
    data.push([x, y]);
  }
}

svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; })
   .attr("r", r)
   .attr("opacity", 0)
   .transition()
   .duration(100)
   .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 100; })
   .attr("opacity", 1);
```

Comment: Eh, well, `.opacity()` isn't part of D3's API, right? A stumble by the great Lars, you won't see that very often ;-) Anyway, do you have any clue as to why the circles will not be drawn one after the other using the OP's approach?

Comment: Thanks for spotting, fixed that -- I sometimes wish D3 would make these things less verbose to type. I would guess that the browser is optimising updating the display as the circles are added so quickly and doesn't do so for every circle, as you'd barely be able to see it anyway.

Comment: That works, but the problem is that I have to wait a long time before the browser starts to show anything. [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/pyf3qsfw/).
I did not understand the single threaded nature of the browser. So the browser is not able to update the ui while it is busy running the javascript loop. A way around that is to return the control back to the browser link in the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551378/javascript-pausing-execution-of-function-to-wait-for-user-input).

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me. Note that this doesn't have anything to do with the browser being single-threaded (it isn't), but the browser optimising how things are drawn by preventing too frequent updates.